# Are stored procedures safe from SQL injections?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a method that inserts records into the database using normal parameterized SQL query.

```
public static void Add(string name, string friendlyName)
    {
    using (var db = Database.Open(_connectionString))
    {
        var sql = "INSERT INTO Tags(Name, UrlFriendlyName) " +
            "VALUES(@0,@1)";
            db.Execute(sql, name, friendlyName);

    }
}
```

I changed the method so that it uses a stored procedure instead

```
public static void Add(string name, string friendlyName)
{
    using (var db = Database.Open(_connectionString))
    {

        // USE STORED PROCEDURE
        var query = "Exec insertTags @name='" + name + "', @urlFriendlyName= '" + friendlyName + "'";
        db.Execute(query);

    }
}
```

The stored procedure looks like the following

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertTags
@name nvarchar(25),
@urlFriendlyName nvarchar(25)
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN Transaction
BEGIN TRY
INSERT INTO dbo.Tags(Name, UrlFriendlyName) 
VALUES(@name, @urlFriendlyName)
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
BEGIN COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
BEGIN ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END
END CATCH

END
```

Both of these methods work just fine. My question is, does the method that utilize the stored procedure provide security against SQL injections like the first one does? Thanks.

**EDIT**

I changed the second method to use parameters instead of string concatenation and it works. Is this safe against SQL injections?

```
public static void Add(string name, string friendlyName)
{
    using (var db = Database.Open(_connectionString))
    {

        // USE STORED PROCEDURE
        var query = "Exec insertTags @0, @1";
        db.Execute(query, name, friendlyName);

    }
}
```

Comment: No. Stored procedures are don't prevent SQL Injection always. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68701/how-does-stored-procedure-prevents-sql-injection and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174003/does-stored-procedure-help-eliminates-sql-injection-what-are-the-benefits-of-s and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2011/02/16/do-stored-procedures-protect-against-sql-injection.aspx

Comment: @SonerGönül your comment is better than the answers below.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use parameters instead of string concatenations. In this case you will be safe

Comment: I edited my question with a method that uses parameters instead of string concatenation. Is it safe this way?

Comment: I am not sure what is going on in your execute, but it should look like that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyy0sz6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx or like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dw70f090%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't. As soon as you construct a SQL statement by concatenating strings together, you are at risk of SQL injection.

For example:

```
"Exec insertTags @name='" + name
```

Someone could pass: "Anything'; DROP TABLE xxx;" for name, and potentially break your database. You can still use parameterized queries with stored procedures, so they can offer the same protection, just not in the way you're calling it in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Any use of string concatenation in your application even when using a stored procedure automatically makes the execution of that code vulnerable to SQL injection.

In ADO.NET, the correct method of executing a stored procedure is to use the `DbCommand` classes with the `CommandType` set to `CommandType.StoredProcedure` and providing the stored procedure parameters in the `Parameters` collection.

Link to MSDN: [System.Data.Common.DbCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand(v=vs.110).aspx)